# How to get the value of last visited URL in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two html pages Those are 1.html and 2.html.

When I visit to 2.html from 1.html page I want to show a message in 2.html page that you have come from 1.html page.

For this purpose I am using `document.referrer` in my 2.html page but when I alert the message I am getting a blank popup.

I am very new to Jquery. I appreciate if any one can resolve this issue.

Comment: show us your code! how are you alerting? why do you even need jQuery for this? i believe this question is inappropriately tagged!

Comment: You might want to do that using [cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery). I would suggest `SESSION` if you would be using PHP.

Answer (score 2):

[As per MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer)

```
var string = document.referrer;
```

> Returns the URI of the page that linked to this page.

Notes:

> The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, via a bookmark). Since this property returns only a string, it does not give you DOM access to the referring page.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var referrer =  document.referrer;
});
```

**Note:-** `document.referrer` works only if the current page is loaded by clicking a link or redirecting on the previous page.